# How to check whether a numeric encoded entity is a valid ISO8859-1 encoding?

Tags: html, kotlin, character-encoding

Let's say I was given random character reference like `&#12345;`. I need a solution to check whether this a valid encoding or not.

I think I can use the [Charset](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-charsets/) lib but I can't fully wrap my mind on how to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer has been rewritten after further research.]

There's no simple answer to this using `Charset`s; see below for a complicated one.

There are simple answers using the character code, but it turns out to depend on exactly what you mean by ISO8859-1!

According to [the Wikipedia page on ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), the character set `ISO8859-1` defines only characters 32–126 and 160–255. So you could simply check for those ranges, e.g.:

```
fun Char.isISO8859_1() = this.toInt() in 32..126 || this.toInt() in 160..255
```

However, that same page also mentions the character set `ISO-8859-1` (note the extra hyphen), which defines all 8-bit characters (0–255), assigning control characters to the extra ones. You could check for *that* with e.g.:

```
fun Char.isISO_8859_1() = this.toInt() in 0..255
```

`ISO8859-1` includes all the *printable* characters, so if you only want to know whether a character has a defined glyph, you could use the former. However, these days most people tend to mean `ISO-8859-1`: that's what many web pages use (those which haven't yet moved on to UTF-8), and that's what the first 256 Unicode characters are defined as. So the latter will probably be more generally useful.

Both of the above methods are of course very short, simple, and efficient; but they only work for the one character set; and it's awkward hard-coding details of a character set, when library classes already have that information.

It seems that [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) objects are mainly aimed at encoding and decoding, so they don't provide a simple way to tell which characters are defined as such. But you *can* find out whether they can encode a given character. Here's the simplest way I found:

```
fun Char.isIn(charset: Charset) =
    try {
        charset.newEncoder()
               .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)
               .encode(CharBuffer.wrap(toString()))
        true
    } catch (x: CharacterCodingException) {
        false
    }
```

That's really inefficient, but will work for all `Charset`s.

If you try this for [`ISO_8859_1`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-charsets/-i-s-o_8859_1.html), you'll find that it can encode all 8-bit values, i.e. 0–255. So it's clearly using the full `ISO-8859-1` definition.